# Remove the use of "tab" button in my webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

i have an horizontal web page and i need to remove the use of the "tab" button of my page because i have a contact form with textboxs in the last **div** and if the user use the "tab" button, no matter in which **div** the user is, it jumps from that page to the last page where my contact form is.

Anyone knows if it's possible to remove it?
Thank you and sorry for my english.

Comment: Did you think about usability? It is user unfriendly to remove the tab.

Comment: I know it's user unfriendly but i can't think about other solution, at least there is any way to stop "tab" from jumping between links and only allow it on text boxes?.

Answer (score 3):

You can try something like

```
$(document).on('keypress', function(e){
     var keyCode =  e.which; 

      if (keyCode == 9) { 
        e.preventDefault(); 
        return false;
      } 
});
```

Comment: Or you can use only `e.which`.

Comment: I wouldn't actually suggest to apply this to document, but rather to sections of document, because user will want to navigate trough form input fields.

Comment: @skmasq, Preventing tab is a bad idea as usability. And I agree with your point

Comment: It's poor design if one needs to prevent tab's

Comment: Look, i have an horizontal web page where i have 5 pages with content and links and 1 web page of contact, if i'm in the first page and i hit "tab" it jumps to the next link and if that link it's in the other page, it will jump to it, how do you prevent that? i'm starting with html5 sorry for being ignorant.

Comment: This is a demo of a similar web page of mine, and it also happens on it. I think this could explain my problem.
http://www.websitecodetutorials.com/code/jquery-plugins/horizontal-website-demo2.php